# Duplicated Java runtime options : what is the order of preference?

Tags: java, jvm, jvm-arguments, java-opts

Considering the following command line

```
java -Xms128m -Xms256m myapp.jar
```

Which settings will apply for JVM Minimum memory (`Xms` option) :  128m or 256m ?

Comment: No typo in question. Xms options is used twice on purpose. This is the substance of the question

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Depends on the JVM, perhaps the version...perhaps even how many paper clips you have on your desk at the time.  It might not even work.  Don't do that.

If it's out of your control for some reason, compile and run this the same way you'd run your jar.  But be warned, relying on the order of the options is a really bad idea.

```
public class TotalMemory
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
         System.out.println("Total Memory: "+Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory());
         System.out.println("Free Memory: "+Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory());
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 - better count those paperclips :-).  Seriously, it is not rocket science to change whatever is passing those ambiguous arguments.

Comment: been trying with different number of paper clips. can't find switch to the first one

Answer (score 74):

As always, check your local JVM's specific implementation but here is a quick way to check from the command line without having to code.

```
> java -version; java -Xmx1G -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -Xmx2G 2>/dev/null | grep MaxHeapSize

java version "1.8.0_25"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_25-b17)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.25-b02, mixed mode)
uintx MaxHeapSize         := 2147483648        {product}
```

So you'll see in this case, the second instance of the argument (2G) is what takes precedence (at least in 1.8) and that has been my experience with most other modern versions as well.

Comment: `java -Xmx1G -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -Xmx2G 2>/dev/null | grep MaxHeapSize`, this way it's easier to deduce.

Answer (score 43):

The IBM JVM treats the rightmost instance of an argument as the winner.  I can't speak to HotSpot, etc..

We do this as there are often deeply nested command lines from batch files where people can only add to the end, and want to make that the winner.

Comment: +1 for actually answering the question instead of pontificating.

Comment: Indeed: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSYKE2_7.0.0/com.ibm.java.zos.70.doc/diag/appendixes/cmdline/cmdline_specifying.html

Answer (score 40):

FTR, OpenJDK 1.7 also seems to take the rightmost value, at least for -Xms.

Comment: +1 for actually answering the question instead of pontificating.

Comment: just like CSS, the later wins

Answer (score 18):

> *Which settings will apply for JVM Minimum memory?*

In the various versions of Java listed below, the "winner" is the right-most value in the argument list. As others have pointed out, it is not a good idea to rely on this, but perhaps this is useful information to share nonetheless.

**Java 1.8.0_172**

```
~ $ java8
java version "1.8.0_172"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_172-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.172-b11, mixed mode)
~ $ java -Xmx1024m -Xmx4024m -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal Test 2>/dev/null | grep MaxHeapSize
    uintx MaxHeapSize                              := 4219469824                          {product}
```

**Java 11.0.3**

```
~ $ java11
java version "11.0.3" 2019-04-16 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.3+12-LTS)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.3+12-LTS, mixed mode)
~ $ java -Xmx1024m -Xmx4024m -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal Test 2>/dev/null | grep MaxHeapSize
   size_t MaxHeapSize                              = 4219469824                                {product} {command line}
```

**OpenJDK 12.0.1**

```
~ $ java12
openjdk version "12.0.1" 2019-04-16
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 12.0.1+12)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 12.0.1+12, mixed mode, sharing)
~ $ java -Xmx1024m -Xmx4024m -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal Test 2>/dev/null | grep MaxHeapSize
   size_t MaxHeapSize                              = 4219469824                                {product} {command line}
```

**AdoptOpenJDK 12.0.1**

```
~ $ java12a
openjdk version "12.0.1" 2019-04-16
OpenJDK Runtime Environment AdoptOpenJDK (build 12.0.1+12)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM AdoptOpenJDK (build 12.0.1+12, mixed mode, sharing)
~ $ java -Xmx1024m -Xmx4024m -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal Test 2>/dev/null | grep MaxHeapSize
   size_t MaxHeapSize                              = 4219469824                                {product} {command line}
```

**OpenJDK 13-ea**

```
~ $ java13
openjdk version "13-ea" 2019-09-17
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 13-ea+22)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 13-ea+22, mixed mode, sharing)
~ $ java -Xmx1024m -Xmx4024m -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal Test 2>/dev/null | grep MaxHeapSize
   size_t MaxHeapSize                              = 4219469824                                {product} {command line}
```

Comment: this behavior remains consistent in Java SE 11.0.14 (build 11.0.14+8-LTS-263), as well as OpenJDK 17.0.1 (build 17.0.1+12-39)

Answer (score 10):

I bet it's the second one. Arguments are usually processed in the order:

```
for( int i=0; i<argc; i++ ) {
  process_argument(argv[i]);
}
```

But if I were writing java argument parser, I'd complain on conflicting arguments.

Answer (score 0):

My experiments show that it takes the maximum value of `xmx`.

So if you pass in `-xmx4g -xmx1g` it will take `4t`, and
if you pass in `-xmx1g -xmx4g` it will still take `4g`.

Comment: This isn't the behaviour I see in  AdoptOpenJDK-11.0.11+9, using `java -version; java -Xmx2G -Xmx1G -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal 2>/dev/null | grep MaxHeapSize`

Comment: I would encourage more, and different, experimentation. my own experiments (detailed in another answer on this same question) show that the max value is not used in Java SE versions 1.8.0, 11.0.3, 11.0.14 as well OpenJDK versions 12.0.1, 13, and 17.0.1. instead, the right-most value is used.