# What will be the priority parameter?

Tags: linux, variables, environment, java-opts

If you define your JAVA_OPTS as such

```
JAVA_OPTS: -Dprogram.name=run.sh -server -Xms2048m -Xmx4096 -server -Xms128m -Xmx512m -Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000 -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=3600000 -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
```

What would be the priority -Xms and -Xmx parameter? The larger 1st one or the last one?

Thanks,

Comment: The `-server` parameter is independent of the `-Xms` and `-Xmx` parameters, which is what it looks like you're _really_ asking about. But why not try it and see for yourself?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Duplicated Java runtime options : what is the order of preference ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2740725/duplicated-java-runtime-options-what-is-the-order-of-preference)

Comment: Hi Sorry. Yes, I'm referring to duplicate runtime options (will edit it). I need to increase the current Xms and Xmx via the run.sh file. `JAVA_OPTS="-Dprogram.name=$PROGNAME -server -Xms2048m -Xmx4096 -Xincgc $JAVA_OPTS"` However when I add it, it does not remove the original setting. That's why I wanted to know the order of preference. Thank you.