# How to determine the Java memory arguments in effect from within a Java process?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, weblogic-10.x

I typically debug my application by starting a WebLogic process from within IntelliJ IDEA.  Both of these application provide ways of specifying optional memory arguments (e.g., -Xms1024m -Xmx2560m -XX:PermSize=1024m, etc.) to the Java command line, and there are various environmental variables (e.g., JAVA_OPTIONS) that might also come into play.

How can I determine which of these specified options "won", i.e., from within the Java process, how can I find out the memory specifications imposed on the Java process?  None of the system properties I've seen seems to show them.

Comment: You can use JMX calls to get the current heap sizes and Runtime to get the maximum memory size.  However, I would use VisualVM as this will show you this information without having to write any code.

Comment: `Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory()` will return the value of `-Xmx` (in bytes); however I don't believe there is a way to have the value of `-Xms`.

Comment: Also, you may want to have a good look at Codahale's Metrics package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use jconsole (which comes with the java jdk) to connect to your webserver:

```
jconsole <pid>
```

You can go to the VM Summary tab to see all of the VM Arguments passed to your webserver. This will also show you current and maximum heap size. If you have duplicated arguments, generally speaking the last memory argument in the list is what is used. You can check here if you have more questions about that.

[Duplicated Java runtime options : what is the order of preference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2740725/duplicated-java-runtime-options-what-is-the-order-of-preference)