# Compare WLS_MEM_ARGS_32BIT and EXTRA_JAVA_PROPERTIES in Oracle WebLogic Server Memory Arguments

Tags: memory, weblogic

With respect to "setDomainEnv.cmd" file for weblogic server (10.3.6), what is the difference between the memory argument set by "set WLS_MEM_ARGS_32BIT=-Xms512m -Xmx1024m" and the argument provided by "set EXTRA_JAVA_PROPERTIES=-Xms512m -Xmx512m".

Answer (score 0):

I don't have that EXTRA_JAVA_OPTIONS being set anywhere in my setDomainEnv.cmd. That said, generally the last memory argument is what gets used if it's set twice:

[Duplicated Java runtime options : what is the order of preference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2740725/duplicated-java-runtime-options-what-is-the-order-of-preference)

Are you sure there's not an if/else somehow wrapping both of those values? When you start your server Weblogic will check for 32-bit  vs 64-bit and a Sun jvm vs. an Oracle jvm to determine what the memory arguments should be.