# Weblogic - Order of JVM Arguments

Tags: weblogic

I've got a Oracle Weblogic server (10.3.6) which is being started with the following JVM arguments:

> Starting WLS with line: /oracle/javahome/jdk1.6.0_29/bin/java -server -Xms512m -Xmx1024m -XX:PermSize=256m -XX:MaxPermSize=768m   <...some more arguments, and then...>   -Xms1024m -Xmx2048m -XX:PermSize=512m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m

Notice that the arguments 'ms', 'mx', 'PermSize' and 'MaxPermSize' each occur twice.

Now, obviously I'd rather not have 2 occurrences (working on resolving that), but in the meantime, for argument's sake, does anyone know which occurrence of each argument the Weblogic JVM will use? The 1st or 2nd?

Thanks.

Comment: You can connect to your server with `jconsole` to find out how much memory has been allocated... or follow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2740725/duplicated-java-runtime-options-what-is-the-order-of-preference But check `setDomainEnv`, `startWebLogic`, and the `Server Start` tab for your server to see where the duplicate comes from.

Answer (score -1):

It will use the first and ignore the second occurrence.

You are getting 2 occurrences because you must have mentioned PATH=...:%PATH% and here PATH already contained the same parameters.

Comment: Actually this answer is incorrect. It can depend on the JVM but in general, it's almost always the 2nd (right most) occurrence that is used. You can use a simple test class to find out. It's already been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2740725/duplicated-java-runtime-options-what-is-the-order-of-preference