# Which JVM options take priority?

Tags: java, memory, jvm, arguments

I followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/880855/increase-the-java-heap-size-permanently) in order to increase the amount of memory that is allocated to the JVM on a system-wide basis.  It seems to work as advertised as far as getting the setting to the Java process.

However, the Java process that I want to increase the memory allocation for is actually being spawned by an opaque third-party process that specifies *its own* memory options when it creates the Java process (and which provides no configuration of the options that it passes, hence the need for the system-wide setting).

So what happens is that *both* settings get passed to the Java process.  Or at least, that's what appears to happen when I use the [approach described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1490869/how-to-get-vm-arguments-from-inside-of-java-application) to view the JVM arguments.  I get something like:

[image]

Is there some precedence order that dictates which setting is used when the same option is specified multiple times (and that guarantees that the same setting will *always* be selected)?

Or is there some other way to check to see which settings are actually being applied?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Duplicated Java runtime options : what is the order of preference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2740725/duplicated-java-runtime-options-what-is-the-order-of-preference)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to check you can do this

```
-Xms128m
-Xmx256m
-Xmx2g
```

and then

```
// allocate 256m
byte[] array = new byte[ 256 * 1024 * 1024 ];
System.out.println(runtime.totalMemory());
```

if its first option that gets picked up it will OOM, otherwise it will proceed and it will show you total memory as > 256m

Comment: Thanks, this works.  As does the approach discussed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2740725/duplicated-java-runtime-options-what-is-the-order-of-preference).  Both indicate that it's the **last** value that takes precedence, at least when using OpenJDK.