# Hive process memory size

Tags: hadoop, hive

Please can you help me understand what is 512mb (highlighed in bold) in Hive context?
Which memory size it is? 
I have set `export HADOOP_HEAPSIZE=4192` in my `hive-site.xml` file

`hadoop@master:~/hive/conf$ ps -ef | grep 'hive'`

> hadoop    5587     1  0 Feb14 ?        00:05:27
>   /usr/lib/jvm/default-jdk/bin/java -Xmx4192m
>   -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dhadoop.log.dir=/home/hadoop/hadoop-2.7.3/logs -Dhadoop.log.file=hadoop.log -Dhadoop.home.dir=/home/hadoop/hadoop-2.7.3 -Dhadoop.id.str=hadoop -Dhadoop.root.logger=INFO,console -Djava.library.path=/home/hadoop/hadoop-2.7.3/lib/native -Dhadoop.policy.file=hadoop-policy.xml -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true **-Xmx512m** -Dhadoop.security.logger=INFO,NullAppender org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar
>   /home/hadoop/hive/lib/hive-metastore-2.3.2.jar
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore

hadoop    9903  8034  0 10:54 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto hive

> hadoop   21646 15918  1 07:37 pts/3    00:03:02
>   /usr/lib/jvm/default-jdk/bin/java -Xmx4192m
>   -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dhadoop.log.dir=/home/hadoop/hadoop-2.7.3/logs -Dhadoop.log.file=hadoop.log -Dhadoop.home.dir=/home/hadoop/hadoop-2.7.3 -Dhadoop.id.str=hadoop -Dhadoop.root.logger=INFO,console -Djava.library.path=/home/hadoop/hadoop-2.7.3/lib/native -Dhadoop.policy.file=hadoop-policy.xml -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true **-Xmx512m** -Dproc_hivecli -Dlog4j.configurationFile=hive-log4j2.properties -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/home/hadoop/hive/conf/parquet-logging.properties
>   -Dhadoop.security.logger=INFO,NullAppender org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar /home/hadoop/hive/lib/hive-cli-2.3.2.jar
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable you edited is for the clients, not the servers, and you don't export anything from the XML files

> To configure the heap size for HiveServer2 and Hive metastore, set the -Xmx parameter in the `HADOOP_OPTS` variable to the desired maximum heap size in `/etc/hive/hive-env.sh`

VS

> To configure the heap size for the Beeline CLI, set the `HADOOP_HEAPSIZE` environment variable in `/etc/hive/hive-env.sh`

Besides that, both values made it though, so you might want to look at

[Duplicated Java runtime options : what is the order of preference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2740725/duplicated-java-runtime-options-what-is-the-order-of-preference)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Just a quick query, what is the different in HADOOP_OPTS and HADOOP_HEAPSIZE parameter ?

Comment: OPTS is more than just the heapsize. Large garbage collection settings and logging